# Pluralize for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I need a help

I'm using simple form for select box. The code is here: `= f.input :dogs, collection: (0..7)`. When render on browser, it will display select box with value from 0 to 7. I want add text behind value when select box dropdown. Eg: 1 dog - 2 dogs. I tried but not work.

Pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
= f.input :dogs, options_for_select([["1 dog", 1], ["2 dogs", 1]])


= f.input :dogs, options_for_select((1..8).map{|x| x==1?  ["#{x} dog",x] : ["#{x} dogs",x] })
```

Comment: Great! A little change: 
`= f.input :dogs, collection: ((1..7).map{|x| x==1?  ["#{x} dog",x] : ["#{x} dogs",x] })`
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A really simple and elegant solution could be something like this:

Create a helper method:

```
def humanize_dogs
  0.upto(7).each_with_object({}) { |c, h| h[pluralize(c, 'dog')] = c }
end
# => {"0 dogs"=>0, "1 dog"=>1, "2 dogs"=>2, "3 dogs"=>3, "4 dogs"=>4, "5 dogs"=>5, "6 dogs"=>6, "7 dogs"=>7}
```

In your form add the next line:

```
= f.input :dogs, collection: humanize_dogs
```

This generates...

```
<select id="#" name="#">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">0 dogs</option>
  <option value="1">1 dog</option>
  <option value="2">2 dogs</option>
  <option value="3">3 dogs</option>
  <option value="4">4 dogs</option>
  <option value="5">5 dogs</option>
  <option value="6">6 dogs</option>
  <option value="7">7 dogs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is answer: `= f.input :dogs, collection: ((1..7).map{|x| x==1?  ["#{x} dog",x] : ["#{x} dogs",x] })`

Comment: Really? You don't need to iterate to check if the value is 1 to show a string or another, you can use the `pluralize` method.

Comment: Yes, agree totally. A my friend have talk about pluralize method, it work perfectly `= f.input :dogs, collection: (0..7).map{ |count| [pluralize(count, 'dog'), count] }`. Thank you.